# Entering Australia with Australian Passport Leaving with American

Tags: us-citizens, dual-nationality, australian-citizens

So I am a dual citizen currently residing in Australia, but I need to go home to America pretty much ASAP (2 days) due to family circumstances. I entered Australia on my now expired Australia passport, would it be okay for me to leave Australia on my valid American passport to go to America? I would be staying there for quite some time and would then update my Australian passport? I still have my Australian passport to show I entered legally, it is just not valid to fly on anymore.

Comment: You will most certainly have to show both passports at passport control when leaving. If you just present the American passport, they will try to match it to an ETA and associated visit details and fail. If you just present the Australian passport they will probably complain about the validity. Not sure if the combination will actually work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Countries generally prefer you to leave on the same passport you entered the country in. Of course this isn't always possible (citizenship change, for example).

The [Home Affairs](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/traveling-as-a-dual-citizen) website notes for dual citizens:

> A dual citizen is a person who is a citizen of 2 or more countries.
>
> You become a dual citizen if you:
>
> are an Australian citizen, are granted citizenship of another country and don't lose your Australia citizenship, or
>       remain a citizen of another country and become an Australian citizen
>
> Australia allows a person to have dual citizenship.

Of course, now you just know they recognise it.

And so they note, regardless, if you have an Australian citizenship:

> Australian citizens entering and leaving Australia
>
> **Australian citizens should use their Australian passport to enter and
>   leave Australia.**
>
> The Australian Border Force has more information on [crossing the
>   border](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/crossing-the-border/at-the-border).
>
> **If you have a passport from another country, you can use that after
>   you leave Australia.**
>
> A passport is the best way to show that you are an Australian citizen.
>   You might still be able to enter Australia if you are an Australian
>   citizen without an Australian passport, but it will be more difficult.
>   The airline might also stop you from boarding a plane to Australia.
>
> Smart Traveller has more information about [travelling as a dual
>   citizen](https://smartraveller.gov.au/guide/Pages/dual-nationals.aspx).

Comment: But "should" is not "must," so this doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: The OP is also asking about *leaving* Australia, not entering.

Comment: @jpatokal didn't I cover leaving? The linked "Australian citizens should use their Australian passport to enter and leave Australia." quote as well as "If you have a passport from another country, you can use that after you leave Australia."?

Comment: @MarkMayo We know it's possible to enter Australia without a valid Australia passport, even though you "should" not.  However, your answer does not clarify whether it's possible to leave without one.